# Trouble in understanding the "Special Comparison Test."

Tags: analysis

Statement of the **Special Comparison Test**

> If as $x$ tends to $\infty$ the function $f(x)\geq0$ is an
>   infinitesimal of order $\lambda>0$ as compared with $\frac{1}{x}$,
>   then the integral $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges for $\lambda>1$
>   and diverges for $\lambda\leq1$.

**Problem** (based on the application of this test):

> Test the integral for
>   convergence.$$\int_{3}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x)(x-1)(x-2)}}$$

**My attempt**: Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x)(x-1)(x-2)}}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Both are infinitesimals as $x$ tends to $\infty$ and $f(x)\geq0$. To find the order recall that if $\lim \frac{f(x)}{(g(x))^\lambda}=c$, where $0<|c|<+\infty$, then the function $f(x)$ is an infinitesimal of order $\lambda$ as compared with $g(x)$. Using this idea, we can find a $\lambda$ such that $$\lim\frac{x^\lambda}{\sqrt{(x)(x-1)(x-2)}}$$ is finite. If $\lambda=3/2$ then notice that the limit, for $x$ tending to $\infty$ is equal to 1. But $\lambda=3/2>1$, which implies that the integral converges.

**Doubt**: Is this proof correct?